# What is the meaning of a matrix eigenvalue to be 0? (Singular matrix, I know but what about it?)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, singularity

$Av=\lambda v \implies$ $Av$ is parallel to $v$.

If one eigenvalue is 0, then the determinant is 0 and the matrix is singular.

What is the meaning of a matrix eigenvalue to be 0?

Is it like $Av$ will disappear from the space?

Any physical meaning or analogy to help understand it?

P.s: I am not looking for equations.

Comment: For me, it simply means the corresponding linear map is *not* injective.

Comment: Very short version: Projecting a vector in 3D into the x-y plane is a linear operation. It has one zero eigenvalue for $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$, the dimension that's getting flattened out. In general, zero eigenvalues represent a projection onto the space perpendicular to those eigenvectors.

Comment: "Is it like $Av$ will disappear from the space?" Multiplying a vector by $0$ will not make it disappear from the space. Likewise, multiplying an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ by the matrix will not make the vector disappear.

Comment: @eyeballfrog That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Linear maps with non-trivial kernel do not have to be projections, and even when they are, they don't have to be orthogonal ones. Your comment makes a *huge* oversimplification.

Comment: I think of it as “collapsing” the space along $v$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First consider the case of a matrix $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Then $x\mapsto Ax$ is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. According to the theory of linear algebra, $A$ can be finally decomposed into dilations in some direction and rotations in some other directions.

A dilation corresponds to a real eigenvalue and an eigenvector, which are, in your case, $\lambda$ and $v$. If $\lambda=0$, then for all vectors in the direction of $v$ we have $A(cv)=cAv=c\lambda v=0$, i.e., the direction $v$ disappears under the action of $A$.

A rotations corresponds to a nonzero complex eigenvalue, which I will not go into details since you seem to be concerned only about the eigenvalue $0$.

An example might help you understand. Let
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
It has two eigenvectors:
$(2,-1)^T$ with e.v. $0$, and $(1,0)^T$ with e.v. $1$. Then you set up a new frame generated by these two vectors, and decompose any other vector in these two directions. Then the action of $A$ as a linear map can be said as follows:

(1) dilate a vector in the direction of $(1,0)^T$ by a factor of $1$.
(2) dilate a vector in the direction of $(2,-1)^T$ by a factor of $0$, i.e., ''disappear''.